# Ruby on Rails - Edit/Update Content on Show layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find out how to implement a system that allows me to update certain fields without navigating away from the current page, and without reloading it.

I've seen this on a lot of websites, including editing comments on StackOverflow.

Example:

You wrote and posted a `Comment`. While looking at all the posted `Comments`, there is a 'Edit' button that changes that `Comment` back into a `text_area` in place, allowing you to update the text, and a button to save it. Then the updated `Comment` looks correct, and you didn't need to navigate or refresh.

I believe what they're doing is:

1. When you click the 'Edit' button, Javascript is generating/displaying a hidden layout with the `text_area`.
2. Clicking 'Save' will send a request off in the background, without refreshing the screen.
3. Javascript will take the updated text and copy it into the old layout, and display that.

Is there any good examples of how to implement this? I'm not even sure what terminology is used for this kind of updating.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This has some info on this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: You can do this using rails form partials with ajax call.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not even sure what to search with ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist many examples to reach your goal.

Give me a try to give you a simple example for a better understanding.

Let's say you have a `Post` model

```
class Post
end
```

Your index page like the following (in controller index `@posts = Post.all`

```
<% #app/views/posts/index.html.erb %>
<div id="posts">
  <%= render @posts %>
</div>
```

The post object partial:

```
<% #app/views/posts/_post.html.erb %>
<div id="<%= dom_id(post)%>">
  <%= post.title %>
</div>
```

And update your `form_for` tags with the remote attribute

```
form_for @post, remote: true
```

Now your create could add the current post to the div#posts or replace the entire div.

```
<% #app/views/posts/create.js.erb %>
$("#posts").append('<%=j(render @post)%>')
```

Your update could update one entry by replacing the div with the `dom_id()` for the updated post.

```
<% #app/views/posts/update.js.erb %>
$("#posts ##{dom_id(@post)}").html('<%=j(render @post)%>')
```

That's all.

Comment: Hello Rob, that makes a lot of sense, but how do I call the `create.js.erb` or `update.js.erb`? What changes do I need to make to my `PostsController` to not redirect but instead use those?

Comment: you have to update your form_for tags with the remote attribute `form_for @post, remote: true`

Comment: Thank you! I looking up more on `remote`, and was able to find this tutorial and got it all working! Seems adding `formt.js {}`    in the create was also needed. http://www.korenlc.com/remote-true-in-rails-forms/